# Attaching extra model to BelongstoMany relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables (users and drinks) with a pivot table, the user has a hasOne relation with profiles table, is there a way to attach the profile table to the pivot table and get all data.

Table **user**

```
id | name | email
```

Table **profile**

```
id | user_id | picture
```

Table **drinks**

```
id | name | price
```

Pivot Table **user_drinks**

```
id | user_id | drink_id | quantity | price | status
```

**Drink Model**

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_drinks', 'drink_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('price', 'quantity')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**User Model**

```
public function drinks()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Drink', 'user_drinks', 'drink_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('price', 'quantity')->withTimestamps();
}

public function profile() {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
     }
```

PS: I don't wanna write this with raw sql query, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you would like to achieve? The answer provided is what I would suggest without knowing more.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't change the tables relation.
I'd use the `->with()` function to get the profile information within the existing relations.

So `$user->drinks()->where('drink_id', $drink_id)->with('profile')->get();` would be my guess.

Comment: I'm actually accessing the relation via a scope. I'm looking for ways to add an extra relation to that scope.